# Is there any alternative solution to multiprocessing.Queue for passing Images between processes?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, queue, ipc, video-processing

We are working on a application which uses live camera feed and python multiprocessing.Queue for passing the data between different processes. We are using a single system/machine for this. We have below processes:
Process 1. Reads frames, performs object detection and it stores frames and object detection results in 2 different queues.
Process 2. This process reads object detection and frames queue. It applies some operations on the frames and object detection results like annotates frames, etc.. It takes more than 1 sec to process 1 sec of frames(30 frames), which is causing the Queues to pile up with images and object detection results. As Queue is getting filled quickly, the system is crashing or ending all processes.

We are trying to externalize the Queues, so system can be stable.

I would really appreciate if someone could point me to a "standard" way working with images.

I am looking for something which can replace Queues, but still provides the same speed and passing the data between processes.

Comment: producer-consumer situation. you want something based on shared memory. you also want synchronization so your consumers only react to new frames, but don't "choke" the producer if a consumer is too slow.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Yes, that's exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: this can be built on top of pthreads API (which works between processes too), probably also on top of what python offers. you just need a "condition" object and whatever else. the shared memory, iirc, you can attach to a name in some namespace provided by the operating system.